# SQL Server query needs performance improvement - left joins on a temp table with groupby rollup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by, left-join

I have inherited a huge query/report SP. It's running super-slow and is not scaling well. There is a lot of left joining going on from the way it's written. It's making a temp table and storing a date range as individual dates in a datetime column, then left joining on this table to get the info from several other tables with a groupby/rollup to get totals for the report. It's written in a way unfamiliar to me. I'm used to the dates/params being in the 'WHERE' clause where Indexes are an advantage.

There has to be a better way of doing this. Maybe just some sage guidance would be great. Code would be even better. I've been trying to think through a CTE approach. There are tons of ISNULL checks and nested CONVERTS to scrape off the time and just leave a date for comparison, very sloppy.

I'm new here so I can't tell you much about the DB yet as far as indexes,etc I've heard there aren't indexes where they need to be etc. This system was built years ago and is on a SQL Server 2008 box. Anyway here's the query:

```
-- these are just sample dates as I have copied this from the SP into a query window since it's all dynamic sql and hard to read as just a red string.   
DECLARE @FromDate date = '2015-06-01'
DECLARE @ToDate date = '2015-06-02'
DECLARE @TempDate date
DECLARE @TempToDate date

-- from here down is the SP
CREATE TABLE #SSTempDates (TempDate DATETIME)

IF @FromDate = ''
    SET @TempDate = (SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), MIN(ImportDate), 101) FROM OrdersViewWImport)
ELSE
    SET @TempDate = @FromDate

IF @ToDate = ''
    SET @TempToDate = (SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),GETDATE(), 101))
ELSE
    SET @TempToDate = @ToDate

WHILE @TempDate < @TempToDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #SSTempDates SELECT @TempDate
    SET @TempDate = DATEADD(D,1,@TempDate)
END

-- done creating the temp table that holds the dates to join on
SELECT CASE WHEN GROUPING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101)) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101) END AS [Date], 
    SUM(ISNULL(SH.QtyShipped,0)) AS [Units Shipped], 
    SUM(ISNULL(SH.ShippedPrice,0)) AS [Pounds Shipped], 
    SUM(ISNULL(C.QtyCancel,0)) AS [Units Cancelled], 
    SUM(ISNULL(C.CancelledPrice,0)) AS [Pounds Cancelled], 
    SUM(ISNULL(PR.OrdersPrinted,0)) AS [Allocated Orders], 
    SUM(ISNULL(SH.OrdersShipped,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(A.OrdersAssigned,0)) AS [Shipped Orders], 
    SUM(ISNULL(PR.QtyPrinted,0)) AS [Items Allocated], 
    SUM(ISNULL(SH.QtyShipped,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(A.QtyAssigned,0)) AS [Items Shipped], 
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101)) = 1 THEN 
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(SUM(PR.QtyPrinted),0) = 0 THEN 0 
            WHEN CAST(CONVERT(DECIMAL,(ISNULL(SUM(SH.QtyShipped),0) + ISNULL(SUM(A.QtyAssigned),0))) / CONVERT(DECIMAL,ISNULL(SUM(PR.QtyPrinted),0)) * 100 AS DECIMAL(19,2)) > 100 THEN 100 
            ELSE CAST(CONVERT(DECIMAL,(ISNULL(SUM(SH.QtyShipped),0) + ISNULL(SUM(A.QtyAssigned),0))) / CONVERT(DECIMAL,ISNULL(SUM(PR.QtyPrinted),0)) * 100 AS DECIMAL(19,2)) END 
        ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(PR.QtyPrinted,0) = 0 THEN 0 
            WHEN CAST(CONVERT(DECIMAL,(ISNULL(SH.QtyShipped,0) + ISNULL(A.QtyAssigned,0))) / CONVERT(DECIMAL,ISNULL(PR.QtyPrinted,0)) * 100 AS DECIMAL(19,2)) > 100 THEN 100 
            ELSE CAST(CONVERT(DECIMAL,(ISNULL(SH.QtyShipped,0) + ISNULL(A.QtyAssigned,0))) / CONVERT(DECIMAL,ISNULL(PR.QtyPrinted,0)) * 100 AS DECIMAL(19,2)) END) END AS [Fill Rate %], 
    CAST(CASE WHEN GROUPING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101)) = 1 THEN ISNULL(SUM(NP.[ID]) / ISNULL((SUM(NP.[ID])+SUM(NP.[NG])+SUM(NP.[ZO])+SUM(NP.[SS])),0) * 100,0) 
        ELSE CASE WHEN SUM(NP.[ID]) = 0 THEN 0 
            ELSE ISNULL(SUM(NP.[ID]) / (SUM(NP.[ID])+SUM(NP.[NG])+SUM(NP.[ZO])+SUM(NP.[SS])) * 100,0) END END AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS [Inv Disc %], 
    CAST(CASE WHEN GROUPING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101)) = 1 THEN ISNULL(SUM(NP.[NG]) / ISNULL((SUM(NP.[ID])+SUM(NP.[NG])+SUM(NP.[ZO])+SUM(NP.[SS])),0) * 100,0) 
        ELSE CASE WHEN SUM(NP.[NG]) = 0 THEN 0 
            ELSE ISNULL(SUM(NP.[NG]) / (SUM(NP.[ID])+SUM(NP.[NG])+SUM(NP.[ZO])+SUM(NP.[SS])) * 100,0) END END AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS [NG %], 
    CAST(CASE WHEN GROUPING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101)) = 1 THEN ISNULL(SUM(NP.[SS]) / ISNULL((SUM(NP.[ID])+SUM(NP.[NG])+SUM(NP.[ZO])+SUM(NP.[SS])),0) * 100,0) 
        ELSE CASE WHEN SUM(NP.[SS]) = 0 THEN 0 
            ELSE ISNULL(SUM(NP.[SS]) / (SUM(NP.[ID])+SUM(NP.[NG])+SUM(NP.[ZO])+SUM(NP.[SS])) * 100,0) END END AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS [SS %],       
    CAST(CASE WHEN GROUPING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101)) = 1 THEN ISNULL(SUM(NP.[ZO]) / ISNULL((SUM(NP.[ID])+SUM(NP.[NG])+SUM(NP.[ZO])+SUM(NP.[SS])),0) * 100,0) 
        ELSE CASE WHEN SUM(NP.[ZO]) = 0 THEN 0 
            ELSE ISNULL(SUM(NP.[ZO]) / (SUM(NP.[ID])+SUM(NP.[NG])+SUM(NP.[ZO])+SUM(NP.[SS])) * 100,0) END END AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS [ZO %], 
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101)) = 1 
        THEN CAST(AVG(CASE WHEN ISNULL(SH.AvgPrice,0) + ISNULL(A.AvgPrice,0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(SH.AvgPrice,0) + ISNULL(A.AvgPrice,0) END) AS DECIMAL(19,2)) 
        ELSE CAST(SUM(ISNULL(SH.AvgPrice,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(A.AvgPrice,0)) AS DECIMAL(19,2)) END AS [AOV], 
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101)) = 1 
        THEN CAST(AVG(CASE WHEN ISNULL(SH.AvgQty,0) + ISNULL(A.AvgQty,0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(SH.AvgQty,0) + ISNULL(A.AvgQty,0) END) AS DECIMAL(19,2)) 
        ELSE SUM(ISNULL(SH.AvgQty,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(A.AvgQty,0)) END AS [UPO] 

    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TempDate FROM #SSTempDates) TD 
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNo) AS OrdersPrinted, SUM(Quantity) AS QtyPrinted, CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR, PrintBatch, 101)) AS PrintBatchDate 
        FROM PickTicketsOrders WITH (NOLOCK) 
        GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR, PrintBatch, 101))) PR ON PR.PrintBatchDate=CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101) 
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OI.OrderNo) AS OrdersShipped, SUM(OI.Quantity) AS [QtyShipped], SUM(OI.ExtPrice) AS ShippedPrice, CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR, S.ShipBatch, 101)) AS ShipDate, 
            CAST(AVG(OI.ExtPrice) AS DECIMAL(19,6)) AS AvgPrice, CAST(AVG(OI.Quantity) AS DECIMAL(19,6)) AS AvgQty 
        FROM Shipments S WITH (NOLOCK) 
        inner join (SELECT OrderNo, GroupNum, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, SUM(ExtPrice) AS ExtPrice FROM OrderItems GROUP BY OrderNo, GroupNum) OI  ON OI.OrderNo = S.OrderNo AND OI.GroupNum = S.GroupNum 
        GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR, S.ShipBatch, 101))) SH ON SH.ShipDate=CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101) 
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OI.OrderNo) AS OrdersAssigned, SUM(OI.Quantity) AS [QtyAssigned], CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR, OA.ActDate, 101)) AS ActDate, 
            CAST(AVG(OI.ExtPrice) AS DECIMAL(19,6)) AS AvgPrice, CAST(AVG(OI.Quantity) AS DECIMAL(19,6)) AS AvgQty 
        FROM OrderActions OA WITH (NOLOCK) 
        INNER JOIN PndShipments P WITH (NOLOCK) ON P.OrderNo=OA.OrderNo AND P.GroupNum=OA.grouplinenum 
        INNER JOIN OrderItems OI WITH (NOLOCK) ON OI.OrderNo=P.OrderNo AND OI.GroupNum=P.GroupNum 
        INNER JOIN Orders O WITH (NOLOCK) ON O.OrderNo=OA.OrderNo 
        WHERE OA.Type=31 
        GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR, OA.ActDate, 101))) A ON A.ActDate=CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101) 
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT SUM(OI.Quantity) AS QtyCancel, SUM(OI.ExtPrice) AS CancelledPrice, CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CC.CancelDate, 101)) AS CancelDate 
        FROM OrderItems OI WITH (NOLOCK) 
        INNER JOIN Cancels CC WITH (NOLOCK) ON CC.OrderNo=OI.OrderNo AND CC.GroupNum=OI.GroupNum 
        GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CC.CancelDate, 101))) C ON C.CancelDate=CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101) 
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR, PrintBatch, 101)) AS TotalNonPickDate, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN NoPickReason Like 'ID%' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS [ID], 
            SUM(CASE WHEN NoPickReason Like 'NG%' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS [NG], 
            SUM(CASE WHEN NoPickReason Like 'SS%' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS [SS], 
            SUM(CASE WHEN NoPickReason Like 'ZO%' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS [ZO] 
            FROM PickTickets WITH (NOLOCK) 
            WHERE PickBatch<>PrintBatch AND NoPickReason IN ('NG*','NG','ID*','ID','SS*','SS','ZO*','ZO') 
            GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR, PrintBatch, 101))) NP ON NP.TotalNonPickDate=CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101)

    WHERE (ISNULL(C.QtyCancel,0) > 0 OR ISNULL(PR.QtyPrinted,0) > 0 OR ISNULL(SH.QtyShipped,0) + ISNULL(A.QtyAssigned,0) > 0 OR 
        ISNULL(NP.[ID],0) > 0 OR ISNULL(NP.[NG],0) > 0 OR ISNULL(NP.[SS],0) > 0 OR ISNULL(NP.[ZO],0) > 0 ) 

    GROUP BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101) WITH ROLLUP ORDER BY [Date]

drop table #SSTempDates
```

Comment: Your SQL is way too complex that one would want to mess with it online without having any sample data at hand and without a clear idea on the purpose. All those aggregates and joins are scary enough (but they may be perfectly right too, who knows). I would also think about CTEs and also it looks like this code is screaming for "cross apply".

Comment: yea, I'm not posting any data, but thanks.

Comment: Put every derived table a #temp and have date a date in every #temp.  And why do you need a distinct in SELECT DISTINCT TempDate?

Comment: I inherited this as I said above, DISTINCT is because some days don't have data, so instead of having an empty row in the report, it is selecting dates from OrdersViewWImport which may not have contiguous dates. Some dates may not exist and some dates have multiple rows, thus DISTINCT

Comment: wait, my bad, this one is just looping to insert dates into the temp table.. what a waste, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

First of whole, check indexes.
Then there are too many operations under:

```
on, where
```

Remove from there any operations like "CONVERT", "ISNULL", "+" etc

Lets see first join

```
    LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNo) AS OrdersPrinted, SUM(Quantity) AS QtyPrinted, CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR, PrintBatch, 101)) AS PrintBatchDate 
    FROM PickTicketsOrders WITH (NOLOCK) 
    GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR, PrintBatch, 101))) PR ON PR.PrintBatchDate=CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101)
```

It would much better to write

```
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNo) AS OrdersPrinted, SUM(Quantity) AS QtyPrinted, CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR, PrintBatch, 101)) AS PrintBatchDate 
    , PrintBatch 
    FROM PickTicketsOrders WITH (NOLOCK) 
    GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(NVARCHAR, PrintBatch, 101))) PR ON PR.PrintBatch=TD.TempDate
```

Every your join  uses CONVERT. Rewrite it like i wrote above.

Second. Look on where
Every 
ISNULL(C.QtyCancel,0) > 0 
will better
C.QtyCancel > 0

because if **C.QtyCancel is null** then  **C.QtyCancel > 0** is false too (default server settings), so we have the same result.
But function ISNULL can broke execution plan.

Another bad things under where
ISNULL(SH.QtyShipped,0) + ISNULL(A.QtyAssigned,0) > 0

it is short to write but it slows your query.

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/t-sql-where/

Comment: Thank you for your input, but as I described above, the CONVERT commands are used to scrape off the time from datetime otherwise 2015-01-01 will be something like  2015-01-01 11:25:24 and the date comparisons won't work, so I cannot remove them. I could replace them with something like DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, xxxx), 0) but in testing performance was worse.

Comment: Yes but that is not a good way to do that IMHO. SQL server 2008 have Date datatype, no? Casting to Date should be better.( or at worst cast to yyyymmdd ISO format )

Comment: Doing DateDiff is the preferred method in this case. The CAST idea I have tried it already, but it didn't work. This query needs a rewrite. I was trying to find someone who could see this from a different angle

Comment: ry to turn big query to several small query. Every left join. 
And evaluate it.
    set @DT = getdate();
    subquery
    print  datediff(ms,@DT,getdate());